# Bucle while si array aún tiene elementos

Tags: javascript

Lo que pretendo es lo siguiente:

- Tengo un array de N elementos.
- Si la longitud del array es par empieza a emparejar elementos.
- Se seleccionan dos elementos aleatorios diferentes.
- Los emparejamientos deben realizarse entre elementos diferentes.
- Si los elementos son diferentes los visualizo y los elimino del array.
- Vuelvo a mostrar los elementos que quedan y los vuelvo a emparejar si son diferentes de forma aleatoria.

El problema es que no me está eliminando los elementos que se seleccionaron aleatoriamente y no termina el while correctamente, a parte no descarto que haya más errores porque no domino javascript.

Este es el código que he desarrollado:

```
  var array = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
  var lengtharray = array.length;

  if(lengtharray%2 == 0){

     msg.channel.sendMessage("Los participantes en el bombo son:");
     msg.channel.sendMessage(array);
     msg.channel.sendMessage("");

     while (array.length > 0) {

        var rand01 = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
        var rand02 = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];

        if (rand01 != rand02) {

           var vs = " vs ";
           msg.channel.sendMessage("Se enfrentan:");
           msg.channel.sendMessage(rand01 + vs + rand02);
           array.splice(rand01, 1);
           array.splice(rand02, 1);
           msg.channel.sendMessage("");
           msg.channel.sendMessage("Quedan los participantes:");
           msg.channel.sendMessage("");
           msg.channel.sendMessage(array);

        }

     }

  } else {

     msg.channel.sendMessage("Número impar de elementos.");

  }
```

**¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?**

- ¿Estoy usando mal `splice`?
- ¿Estoy usando mal `rand`?

Al ejecutar el script esto es lo que sale:

```
Los participantes en el bombo son:
A
B
C
D
E
F
Se enfrentan:
F vs D
Quedan los participantes:
C
D
E
F
Se enfrentan:
F vs C
Quedan los participantes:
E
F
Se enfrentan:
E vs F
Quedan los participantes:
```

Comment: En el splice estás usando el valor del array y no la posicion del array.

Comment: Me daba que el error efectivamente estaba en el splice y la posición. Pero no sé como puedo hacerlo usando la posición si estoy usando el nombre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenés 2 errores:

- Estás eliminando correctamente los elementos del Array, el problema es que estás mostrando el mensaje de "Quedan los participantes" adentro del while aunque el array tenga 0 elementos.
- El splice lo estás haciendo con al valor del array en esa posición, y no con la posición como debería ser.

**Un fix rápido para esto puede ser:**

```
var array = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
var lengtharray = array.length;

if (lengtharray % 2 == 0) {

    msg.channel.sendMessage("Los participantes en el bombo son:");
    msg.channel.sendMessage(array);
    msg.channel.sendMessage("");

    while (array.length > 0) {

        var rand01 = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
        var rand02 = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];

        if (rand01 != rand02) {

            var vs = " vs ";
            msg.channel.sendMessage("Se enfrentan:");
            msg.channel.sendMessage(rand01 + vs + rand02);
            array.splice(array.indexOf(rand01), 1);
            array.splice(array.indexOf(rand02), 1);
            if (array.length > 0) {
                msg.channel.sendMessage("");
                msg.channel.sendMessage("Quedan los participantes:");
                msg.channel.sendMessage("");
                msg.channel.sendMessage(array);
            }
        }

    }

} else {

    msg.channel.sendMessage("Número impar de elementos.");

}
```

Comment: Si te fijas en el resultado no está eliminando del array los elementos que había seleccionado antes. En el primer paso elimina por ejemplo A que no se había seleccionado y vuelve a mostrar F.

Comment: Ahh entonces tenías este error también :P

Usa indexOf(rand), para eliminar correctamente el elemento con el index del Array, deje el code corregido.

Comment: Gracias bibito, has dado con la solución.

Answer (score 0):

Veo un par de problemas, el primero es que en el splice usas el valor del array y no su posición.
Después, en el segundo splice, como ya eliminaste un valor antes, la posición a eliminar se ha podido modificar.
Por ejemplo, si quiero eliminar las posiciones 1 y 3 de [a,b,c,d]
al eliminar la 1 queda [a,c,d] de manera que la posición 3, ahora es la 2.
Una posible solución, es elegir el segundo jugador después de eliminar el primero. Y de paso, al eliminar el primer jugador, ya no hay la posibilidad de repetirlo, así que nos ahorramos la comprobación, un ejemplo seria este:

```js
var array = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
if(array.length%2 == 0){
  document.write("Los participantes en el bombo son:<br>");
  document.write(array+"<br>");
  while (array.length > 0) {
   var rand01 = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
   var jugador1= array.splice(rand01, 1);
   var rand02 = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
   var jugador2= array.splice(rand02, 1);
   document.write("Se enfrentan:<br>");
   document.write(jugador1 + " vs " + jugador2+"<br>");
   if (array.length){
     document.write("Quedan los participantes:<br>");
     document.write(array+"<br>");
    }
  }
} else {
  document.write("Número impar de elementos.");
}
```